# Getting the md5 hash without getting the whole file in google cloud storage

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

My goal is to get the object metadata without downloading the object/blob using the java api(https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects#resource).
I am able to do it with JSON API but unable to find the equivalent for the java API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[storage.objects.get](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get) can return an object's data *or* metadata. For the Java client, one of the [`storage.get`](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/storage/Storage.html#get-com.google.cloud.storage.BlobId-) methods can be used to retrieve the metadata (as opposed to `storage.reader` which can read the data).

Once you have the result, you can get the MD5 from [`BlobInfo.getMd5`](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/storage/BlobInfo.html#getMd5--) method.

Comment: Thanks, it is now clear after testing that the storage.get does not download the content as i was afraid it might!